# iOS verify certificate by CA locally

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssl, ssl-certificate, rsa

My app contains a public certificate (cert A) that is used for https connection. It works by using this method `URLSession:didReceiveChallenge:completionHandler:` 
But I would like to verify certificate (cert B) that is downloaded with additional data from server. Cert A is CA for cert B. 
I cant find any solutions.

I use X.509 standard. (cert A is .pfx and cert B is .der)